# How to use properties with an integral overflow (byte)?

Tags: c#, memory, properties, byte, integer-overflow

I am fairly new to programming and C#, and I am creating a game using C# 9.0 in which all instances of `Entity` have certain stats. I want to be able to change their private data fields using properties, though I'm not entirely sure how properties work. I know they are useful in encapsulation as getters and setters.

**Context**:

- I am trying to optimize code and decrease memory usage where possible
- The byte field `str` should be variable (through events, training, etc.), but have a "ceiling" and "floor"

  - If `dog.str` = 253, then `dog.Str += 5;` should result in `dog.str` being 255
  - If `dog.str` = 2, then `dog.Str -= 5;` should result in `dog.str` being 0

```
private byte str;
public short Str
{
    get => str;
    set
    {
        if (value > byte.MaxValue) str = byte.MaxValue;       //Pos Overflow
        else if (value < byte.MinValue) str = byte.MinValue;  //Neg Overflow
        else str = (byte)value;
    }
}
```

**Questions**:

- Since the property is of datatype Short, does it create a new private backing field that consumes memory? Or is `value`/`Str{set;}` just a local variable that later disappears?

  - Does the property `public float StrMod {get => (float)(str*Effects.Power);}` create a backing field? Would it be better to just create a method like `public float getStrMod()` instead?
- Is this code optimal for what I'm trying to achieve? Is there some better way to do this, considering the following?

  - If for some reason the Short overflowed (unlikely in this scenario, but there may be a similar situation), then I would end up with the same problem. However, if extra memory allocation isn't an issue, then I could use an int.
  - The `{get;}` will return a Short, which may or may not be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:**

No it doesn't, its backing field is `str`.

**Question 2:**

**Profile your code** first instead of making random changes in hope to reduce memory usage.

*"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"*, do you really have such issues at this point ?

Personally I'd use `int` and use same type for property and backing field for simplicity.

This would avoid wrapping such as assigning `32768` which would then result as `-32768` for `short`.

Side note, don't think that using `byte` necessarily results in 1 byte, if you have tight packing requirements then you need to look at `StructLayoutAttribute.Pack`.

Other than that I see nothing wrong with your code, just get it to work **first** then optimize it!

---

Here's how I'd write your code, maybe you'll get some ideas from it:

```
class Testing
{
    private int _value;

    public int Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set => _value = Clamp(value, byte.MinValue, byte.MaxValue);
    }

    private static int Clamp(int value, int min, int max)
    {
        return Math.Max(min, Math.Min(max, value));
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Different scenarios:

```
class Testing
{
    private int _value1;

    public int Value1 // backing field is _value1
    {
        get => _value1;
        set => _value1 = value;
    }

    public int Value2 { get; set; } // adds a backing field

    public int Value3 { get; } // adds a backing field

    public int Value4 => 42; // no backing field
}
```

As you might have guessed, properties are [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for methods, they can do 'whatever' under the hood compared to a field which can only be assigned a value to.

Also, one difference with a method is that you can browse its value in the debugger, that's handy.

Suggested reading:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Finally, properties are expected to return quickly, else write a method, and possibly `async` if it's going to take a while (advantage to method in this case as properties can't be `async`).

Comment: Okay, cool! And thank you for the advice. I just figured with the way it is already, it would be difficult to change in the future. I was thinking of something like your Clamp() method but forgot how to implement it abstractly (since I've done something like that before). The max and min values were arbitrary, since it was just the datatype's limits (now I can make it something proper).

Comment: I apologize for this lack of etiquette, but I edited my first question right before you answered, if you look for "StrMod." If anyone could also answer that, I can close this question (in scenarios like this, should I just make another post?).

Answer (score 0):

@aybe answer covers main thing about you question. I would like to add additional info to your 2nd question. You should consider on which platform you write application. There is a [**word** term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)):

> In computing, a word is the natural unit of data used by a particular
> processor design. A word is a fixed-sized piece of data handled as a
> unit by the instruction set or the hardware of the processor. The
> number of bits in a word (the word size, word width, or word length)
> is an important characteristic of any specific processor design or
> computer architecture.

If processor has 64 bit word, then every variable which type is less than 64 bits will still occupy 64 bits in memory. Keep in mind that variable of given type will be handled as given type and size in memory doesn't impact range, overflow or underflow - arithmetic will be processed for given type.

In short - if you have 64-bit desktop processor and you will use only `short` variables, then you will not observe any memory savings in comparison to declaring `int` variables.